# xpath preceding-sibling not working

Tags: xpath

I am trying to click on the first button which deletes the item which is the second button.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group">
       <button class="btn btn btn-danger" name="delete" type="button">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
     <span class="class"></span>
  </td>
  <td>
     <button class="btn" name="item" type="button">
  </td>
</tr>
```

XPath

```
//button[contains(.,'${ITEM}')]/preceding-sibling::button[@name='delete']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're just not showing us the button text in your example HTML, since neither of your buttons seems to have any content.

`preceding-sibling` would not work here, since the two buttons are not siblings. However `preceding::button` should work in this case. Note the `[1]` at the end which is needed in order to select the closest match:

```
//button[contains(.,'${ITEM}')]/preceding::button[@name='delete'][1]
```

The following should also work, and is in my opinion a bit cleaner:

```
//tr[.//button[contains(., '${ITEM}')]]//button[@name  ='delete']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using preceding::button didn't work for me as it was selecting the first delete button that it found on the page but the second worked well.

Comment: Ah, yes. You would need a `[1]` at the end if you're using `preceding::`. Updated my answer just to be thorough.

Comment: Does  `preceding::button[1]` select the first match, or the *closest* match (i.e. the last match)?

Comment: @jpaugh It selects the closest one. The `preceding...` and `ancestor...` axes are known as "reverse axes": https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I knew that `preceding-sibling` worked that way, which is why I asked. I'll edit in "closest," because it seems less confusing to refer to document-order unambiguously.